# How to find the current Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j

Here is what I get when I start the console:
[image: Neo4j Console Startup Error]

I click Yes. Here is the Neo4j console 
[image: Neo4j Console]

However, there is no such folder called c:\Temp\Test\Test\Neo4jTest.

When I click on the browser link, Chrome opens and a database with artifacts is loaded. Where is that database? How do I figure out what database has been opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default location of the database is **$NEO4J_HOME\databases\** and the default directory of the database is **graph.db**.

You can also view/update the database location from conf file: **$NEO4J_HOME\conf\neo4j.conf**.

```
# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=graph.db

# Paths of directories in the installation.
dbms.directories.data=C:/MyNeoDB/
```